# Prevent child elements of the div from loosing focus after clicking outside the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a simple "website" that behaves like this:

1. Clicked paragraph receives focus and changes background color to red.
2. When user clicked one of the paragraphs (it received  focus and changed color to red) and then user clicks other paragraph, the "old" paragraph looses focus and red color and passes it to the "new" clicked paragraph.
3. When user clicked one of the paragraphs (it received  focus and changed color to red) and then user clicks the background (projectsDiv) or any other element of the website the paragraph looses focus and red color.

I want the website to behave like this:

1. Same as above
2. Same as above
3. When user clicked one of the paragraphs (it received  focus and changed color to red) and then user clicks the background (projectsDiv) the paragraph looses focus and red color. Clicking any other element of the website doesn't affect focus of the paragraphs inside projectsDiv.

Here is a code:

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="projectsDiv">
        <p tabindex="0">P1</p>
        <p tabindex="0">P2</p>
        <p tabindex="0">P3</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tagsDiv">
        <button id="Tag1" class="Tag">Tag1</button>
        <button id="Tag2" class="Tag">Tag2</button>
        <button id="Tag3" class="Tag">Tag3</button>
    </div>

    </div>
```

```
#projectsDiv p:focus {
    background-color: red;
}

#projectsDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I believe this cannot be done with CSS and focus selectors. You may need to use JavaScript and click event listeners instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need JavaScript. Just use classes to keep track of which element got clicked last.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#projectsDiv, p").forEach(element=>{
  element.addEventListener("click", event=>{
    if (document.querySelector(".lastClicked")) {
      document.querySelector(".lastClicked").classList.remove("lastClicked")
    }
    event.target.classList.add("lastClicked")
    event.stopPropagation()
  })
})
```

```css
#projectsDiv p.lastClicked {
    background-color: red;
}

#projectsDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div id="projectsDiv">
        <p tabindex="0">P1</p>
        <p tabindex="0">P2</p>
        <p tabindex="0">P3</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tagsDiv">
        <button id="Tag1" class="Tag">Tag1</button>
        <button id="Tag2" class="Tag">Tag2</button>
        <button id="Tag3" class="Tag">Tag3</button>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: It works but this condition of if statement seems werid to me. Can you explain it?

Comment: The first `<p>` you click on, it will try to remove the class from the last thing you clicked on. But there is nothing with that class, so it would cause an error. So I used `if (document.querySelector(".lastClicked"))` to catch that case. This statement will check to see if there are any elements that have the class `"lastClicked"`, instead of assuming that there are and causing errors.

Comment: One more thing: clicking on the #projectsDiv fires up a callback function ones, but clicking one of the paragraphs fires up a callback function twice because when you click a paragraph you're also clicking a #projectsDiv. How to fix this?

Comment: Good catch. I just added `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not comfortable with Javascript you can use check-box and labels.

```css
input[name="_radio"]{
  display: none;
}

#projectsDiv input:checked+p {
    background-color: red;
}

#projectsDiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="projectsDiv">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="_radio">
      <p tabindex="0">P1</p>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="_radio">
      <p tabindex="0">P2</p>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="_radio">
      <p tabindex="0">P3</p>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div id="tagsDiv">
    <button id="Tag1" class="Tag">Tag1</button>
    <button id="Tag2" class="Tag">Tag2</button>
    <button id="Tag3" class="Tag">Tag3</button>
  </div>

</div>
```